# django test : accessing database from a form returns empty list

Tags: python, django, pytest

I'm using a Django form, containing a ChoiceField list. This list content is retrieved from the form, using orm. 
It works in the application, but in the test, the utility method returns an empty content.
Before I create the form, I'm querying the same table as the utility method, and it returns 3 records.
Any idea why the utility method considers the table empty ?

## 1) the form :

```
class JournalForm(forms.Form):
    journal_id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
    journal_name = forms.CharField(label=ugettext('Journal name'), max_length=100, required=False)
    list_field = list()
    list_field.append(('0',ugettext('select')))
    list_field = list_field + getFieldOfInterestList()
    journal_fieldOfInterest = forms.ChoiceField(initial='0', choices = list_field, label=ugettext('Field of interest'), widget=forms.Select(), required=False)
```

## 2) the utility method :

```
def getFieldOfInterestList():
    try:
        interest_list = list()
        for field in FieldOfInterest.objects.all().order_by('name'):
            interest_list.append((str(field.id_field),field.name))
        return interest_list     
    except Exception as ex:
        print("an error in getFieldOfInterestList() : " + str(ex))
        return list()
```

## 3) the test :

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def testJournals(self):
  # this query returns 3 fields, previously added in this test (so test database is not empty)
  print("nb fields = " + str(FieldOfInterest.objects.all().count()))
  journalForm = JournalForm(
          initial={
                'journal_name': 'Aquatic Botany',
                'journal_fieldOfInterest': 3,
  })  
  print("form = " + str(journalForm))
  # returns False
  print("is valid = " + str(journalForm.is_valid()))
```

Printed form should have more options in the select, but only contains the default one :

```
<tr><th><label for="id_journal_name">Journal name:</label></th><td><input id="id_journal_name" maxlength="100" name="journal_name" type="text" value="Aquatic Botany" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_journal_fieldOfInterest">Field of interest:</label></th><td><select id="id_journal_fieldOfInterest" name="journal_fieldOfInterest">
<option value="0">select</option>
</select></td></tr>
```

Thank you for reading me.

Comment: Most probably an exception triggered `return list()`.

Comment: I didn't noticed earlier : when I launch pytest, the exception is displayed before listing all the test cases: an error in getFieldOfInterestList() : Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.

Comment: This mark @pytest.mark.django_db is already included below the test method, so still stuck.